# how can I specify multiple runTargets in a single Pom when using gwt maven plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

I have a gwt maven project with multiple modules and different host pages using gwt maven plugin. Though while testing I am able to specify only one runTarget configuration as

```
<runTarget>UiAddressBook.html</runTarget>
```

in the plugin execution configuration. This is a problem since every now and then I am needed to comment / uncomment one or the other runTarget tags.

Is there a way I can specify multiple runTargets and then choose which one to debug / run through the super dev window that shows up when I do gwt:run ?

Answer (score 0):

I think we are out of luck. Apparently it is not able to do that right now.

http://iswwwup.com/t/04fec7d9bb62/java-how-can-i-specify-multiple-runtargets-in-a-single-pom-when-using-gwt-m.html